# jQuery disable child nodes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to disable every input field in a specific part of a web form whenever a radio button is set to the "No" option (and revert this when "Yes" is selected, but am not getting it working properly. I currently have this code for "watching" the radio buttons and enabling/disabling as required:

```
jQuery("#ReportOn").change(function () {
    if(jQuery("#ReportOff").is(":checked")) {
        // Everything working up until here , but below command does nothing.
        jQuery("#reportform > input").attr("disabled", true);
    } else if(jQuery("#ReportOn").is(":checked")) {
        jQuery("#reportform > input").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
    <input type="radio" name="report" id="ReportOn" value="1" /><label for="ReportOn">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="report" id="ReportOff" value="0" /><label for="ReportOff">No</label>
    <div id="reportform">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="ReportTitle" />
        <input type="text" name="subtitle" id="ReportSubtitle" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Whenever the Reporting radio button is set to No, the rest of the form should be disabled.

What am I missing here that prevents it from working?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console/firebug?

Comment: Only this message shows up in the Chrome console, but it looks harmless (informational message): (4) event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. I don't have any event.layerX/layerY reference in my own code, perhaps it's in the jquery core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
jQuery("#reportform > input")
```

to:

```
jQuery("#reportform input")
```

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference since the `input` elements are direct children of `#reportform`.

Comment: Perhaps it shouldn't make a difference, but yet it does. Removing the > from the selector did just the trick! Thanks.

Comment: probably your script are adding something when your script is running. Try running jQuery("#reportform") in your browser console to see how it's constructed when the scripts are running.

Answer (score 2):

Here´s another solution for the same task;

```
$('input[name="report"]').change(function(){
    var disabled = ($(this).val() !== "1");
    $('#reportform input').attr("disabled", disabled); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a whole lot cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got some error like two forms with the same id?
Because it's working for me, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/JqqGb/

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to work.

Make sure to put it *after* the two DOM elements are declared in the HTML (ReportOn, ReportOff). The script is not aware of their existence.

This will work:

```
<div id="something"></div>
<script>$("#something").text('hello');</script>
```

This one won't:

```
<script>$("#something").text('hello');</script>
<div id="something"></div>
```

To avoid these kind of problems you should run the script after the document has been entirely loaded -- document.ready() method.